# Linux Command to Make Directory Tree in 1 command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

hi there i would like the command to make the directorys like this in one command 
http://imgur.com/qArsAIb

would like to know the struture to do this

THANKS

Comment: Welcome. Are you referring to recursive directory listing from the command line, along the lines of the `-r` option of the ls command? `ls -lr` shows it in a longer format. Or do you mean something in a desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) (try `man mkdir`):

```
SYNOPSIS
       mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...

DESCRIPTION
       Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

       -p, --parents
              no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

So you can just use:

```
mkdir -p folder1/subfolder1 folder1/subfolder2 folder2/aap folder3/noot folder3/mies/piet
```

And `find` would then return:

```
.
./folder2
./folder2/aap
./folder1
./folder1/subfolder2
./folder1/subfolder1
./folder3
./folder3/noot
./folder3/mies
./folder3/mies/piet
```

Comment: Or even more compressed: `mkdir {folder1/{subfolder1,subfolder2},folder2/aap,folder3/{noot,mies/piet}}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're talking about printing the directory tree in terminal, there's a package called `tree` that lets to do that.
Install the package if it's not already installed. Since you tagged `ubuntu`, here's how you'd install it in Ubunbu:
`sudo apt-get install tree`

Then you can learn about it with `tree --help`.
`tree -d`
prints the directory list just the way as shown in the linked image only without graphics element and ability to access directories with mouse, obviously.

You can also specify how deep you wish to dig into the directory tree.

`tree -d -L 2`

prints the directories that are upto 2 level deep.
And here's what it looks like.

```
@bibek: cd ~/Git
@bibek: tree -d -L 2
.
├── android-platform
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── android-sdk
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── android-sdk-build-tools
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── android-sdk-platform-tools
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── android-studio
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── dcron
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── google-chrome
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
├── pulseaudio-ctl
│   ├── pkg
│   └── src
└── xf86-input-evdev-ahm
    └── src
```